use of @import when modules are disabled RNDocumentPicker.h
My Xcode project is showing error
Parse Issue
=> Use of @import when modules are disabled
RNDocumentPicker.h
My settings:
"Enable Modules" is set to Yes ;
Link Frameworks Automatically is set to Yes ;
And i'm still getting this error:

Can anyone help?
